# How to make the pull-left/pull-right inside cause it goes outside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've style `border: 1px solid black;` to determine if it is correct box, but it overlap and goes outside. This is my html

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">This page is temporarily disabled by the site administrator for some reason.</div> 
                <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                    <p>Drink whaterver jklasd jklasd jklnxm,c kasdk jj jjjjs lasd jklasd m,zxc asd kljaskd kljasd kl</p>
                    <div style="border: 1px solid black; display: block;" class="pull-left">
                        <div class="row">
                            <p>By <a href="#">Jerald Patalinghug</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            Tags: <a href="#">Funny</a>, <a href="#">Wtf</a>, <a href="#">Nice</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="border: 1px solid black;" class="pull-right">
                        <div id="votes">
                            <div class="row">
                                                            <a href="#" data-card_id="26" class="vote upvote btn btn-default">
                                    <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" data-card_id="26" class="vote downvote btn btn-default">
                                    <span class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></span>
                                </a>
                                                        </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <center>
                                    <span class="vote_count">1</span> points
                                </center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and this is the image

[image]

look, the inside of `div.pull-left` are going outside.

**EDIT1**
Thanks guys, What I did was remove `class="row"` on every div

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">This page is temporarily disabled by the site administrator for some reason.</div> 
                <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                    <p>Drink whaterver jklasd jklasd jklnxm,c kasdk jj jjjjs lasd jklasd m,zxc asd kljaskd kljasd kl</p>
                    <div style="border: 1px solid black; display: block;" class="pull-left">
                        <div>
                            <p>By <a href="#">Jerald Patalinghug</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            Tags: <a href="#">Funny</a>, <a href="#">Wtf</a>, <a href="#">Nice</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="border: 1px solid black;" class="pull-right">
                        <div id="votes">
                            <div>
                                                            <a href="#" data-card_id="26" class="vote upvote btn btn-default">
                                    <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" data-card_id="26" class="vote downvote btn btn-default">
                                    <span class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></span>
                                </a>
                                                        </div>
                            <div>
                                <center>
                                    <span class="vote_count">1</span> points
                                </center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: can you please add your style?

Comment: We need to see the styles please. Though from the looks of it, it probably just need the position type and float adding/changing.

Comment: no style, just pure bootstrap,

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vPU9T/4/ see here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the

```
<div class="row">
```

inside each of the bordered div's - these are adding -15px to the left and right.  These are only to be used when you are nesting inside .container or .col-sm-12 (for example).

This is a good read if you're not 100% sure on how the bootstrap grid works:

http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

Comment: what is my separate to make that like design?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that comment @StormSpirit

Answer (score 0):

Use class container-fluid along with pull-left/pull-right.

Solution:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">This page is temporarily disabled by the site administrator for some reason.</div>
    <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
        <p>Drink whaterver jklasd jklasd jklnxm,c kasdk jj jjjjs lasd jklasd m,zxc asd kljaskd kljasd kl</p>
        <div style="border: 1px solid black; display: block;" class="pull-left container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <p>By <a href="#">Jerald Patalinghug</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                Tags: <a href="#">Funny</a>, <a href="#">Wtf</a>, <a href="#">Nice</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid black;" class="pull-right container-fluid">
            <div id="votes">
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="#" data-card_id="26" class="vote upvote btn btn-default">
                        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" data-card_id="26" class="vote downvote btn btn-default">
                        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <center>
                        <span class="vote_count">1</span> points
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Solution image]

Apply padding in style to have nice look

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 2%; display: block;" class="pull-left container-fluid">

<div style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 2%" class="pull-right container-fluid">
```

[image: Solution image with padding]